# What is meant by 'pause' when async function await expression 'pauses' execution?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise

I am very new to the concept of asyncronicity in Javascript and I wanted to make sure I am not misinterpreting what I am reading.

Consider this pseudo code in some Angular app:

```
async ngOnInit() {

this.responseObject = await this.myService.myGetRequest();

//do some more stuff down here

}
```

My understanding is that the ngOnInit() will 'pause' or stop execution at await, and NOT execute the code below that line until the promise object(data) is returned?  Correct?

Comment: Not until the Promise is *returned*, but until it's *resolved*, until the data it's resolved with is available to be assigned to the property.

Comment: I don't understand.  return only terminates the execution in my case a get request is resolved once the data is available, no?

Comment: Do you understand how `then` callbacks (or asynchronous callbacks in general) work?

Answer (score 2):

The async function declaration will return a Promise that is resolved with the returned valued from your function call.

If you add the await expression, it will stop the async execution and wait until your promise is resolve to continue executing the other instructions in your code, somehow making it behave like a 'synchronous' function.

Do some reading over here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: What is meant by "*the async execution*"?

Answer (score 1):

`await` used within an `async` function awaits the fulfillment of a `Promise` value or converts the variable to a `Promise`.

Yes, you are correct the code at next line will not be executed until the previous line which uses `await` has returned a fulfilled `Promise` or the value is converted to a `Promise`.

---

Note, it is not clear what the pattern

```
await this.responseObject = await this.myService.myGetRequest();
```

is expected to achieve. The first `await` should be able to be omitted

```
this.responseObject = await this.myService.myGetRequest();
```

Comment: Sorry first await was not intentional.  Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the above answers because it's not just about the promise finishing, it's about whether javascript's task queue is in control. Take the following code for example:

```
function delay(message, timeoutInMilliSeconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(message)
      resolve('resolved');
    }, timeoutInMilliSeconds)
  });
}

delay("Finished Outer Timeout", 0)
async function asyncCall() {
  console.log("Before Await")
  await delay("Finished Inner Timeout", 2000)
  console.log(`After Await`);
}
asyncCall()
```

If await only waited for the promise to conclude, we would expect the ordering to be

1. Before Await
2. Finished Inner Timeout
3. After Await
4. Finished Outer Timeout

The outer timeout is placed on the task queue, the main script runs until the await, awaits the inner timeout, then continues until completion.

In actuality the ordering is:

1. Before Await
2. Finished Outer Timeout
3. Finished Inner Timeout
4. After Await

Javascript isn’t waiting on the promise, it’s changing who is in control between the main script or the task queue. Await indicates to the runtime to put the task queue in charge until the promise resolves, not halt everything for that one promise. Note there may be differences depending on your browser, but this is generally how Javascript async/await works.

Work Cited:

- https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/
- https://medium.com/@sadia.islam.badhon/callback-queue-vs-microtask-queue-9dc6a790330e
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queuing-tasks